# How to capture local HTTP traffic

Tags: java, c++, http

I am developing web server where client makes HTTP request to server s1 and server s1 makes HTTP request to server s2 and server s3. Now could you let me know how can I capture HTTP requests/response traffic from client to s1 and s1 to s2 and s3? all servers are running on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  Its an all purpose packet capture program with a set of useful filters for looking through what was sent/received.

Comment: but can wireshark capture local traffic? as my client and server all running on my local machine.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't.  You can just filter for localhost/127.0.0.1 or your lan ip depending on how the servers are set up.  If they're generating packets, Wireshark will capture them.  If you are using a form of interprocess communications, you may need to change the capture device Wireshark uses.

Comment: That is not a great tool for http requests. its on the TPC/IP layer and good luck working all that shit out.

Answer (score 0):

you may install  Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) like the fiddler software. 
it records everything you need.
[Fiddler link] http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: but i think fiddler will be only able to capture traffic from client to s1, could you let me know if it will be able to capture traffic from s1 to s2 and s1 to s3?

Comment: since all the servers are installed on the localmachine it might be able to catch. not sure of it. need to give a try.